# Sqlite database cannot be accessed after installation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I have created a WPF application and I have used a visual studio setup project inside the original solution to create an installer. This installer is created in a correct way and install the application on the system.

The problem is the fact that inside the application a sqlite database need to be created. Until the application is inside visual studio no problem are present, but once installed inside the main window an exception is raised:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\User\TestApp\database.sqlite' denied

The code I use inside the app is the following:

```
if (!File.Exists("database.sqlite"))
{
    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("database.sqlite");
    SQLiteConnection sQLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.sqlite;Version=3;");
    sQliteConnection.setPassword("1234");
    sQliteConnection.Open();
}
```

Can you tell where the problem is? I need to place those elements in a special folder that is accessible after the installation? Or there is another method to ensure the app works after the installation on target machine?

Comment: You should install writable files to the installing user's LocalAppData folder, under a custom product folder for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in the Program Files or Program Files (x86), or any folder underneath, are typically set for read-only access unless your program is run elevated. This requires any write-access files or databases to be located elsewhere. Depending on what you're putting into it, ApplicationData or LocalApplicationData (from Environment.GetFolderPath) are the typical locations.